# SQL arithmetic with variable operator

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a query that generates the results of the following where fldNum is a float field, fldOp is a nvarchar field which returns the values of either '/' or '*', and fldCalc is varchar field which actually contains numbers; when I attempt to execute this it won't work at all however, I get an error of nvarchar to float conversion error...

```
                                   ([fldNum] + [fldOp] + Convert(float,[fldCalc]))
example data if fldOp is a '/'     (0.5533/34)
```

I used a case statement such as the following, which works fine...

```
(CASE WHEN [fldOp] = '/' THEN ([fldNum]/Convert(float,[fldCalc])) 
 ELSE ([fldNum]*Convert(float,[fldCalc])) END)
```

I need something that is more dynamic however in the case that I need to add a + or - to the fldOperator field. Is there anyway of doing this?

Comment: Case is best option. 
`CASE [fldOp]
WHEN '/' THEN ([fldNum]/Convert(float,[fldCalc]))
WHEN '*' THEN ([fldNum]*Convert(float,[fldCalc]))
WHEN '+' THEN ([fldNum]+Convert(float,[fldCalc]))
WHEN '-' THEN ([fldNum]-Convert(float,[fldCalc]))
END`

Answer (score 1):

You could try a dynamic query. The following gives you the idea

```
DECLARE @num1 float
DECLARE @num2 float
DECLARE @op nvarchar
DECLARE @sSql nvarchar(500)

SET @num1 = 0.5533
SET @num2 = 34.0
SET @op = '/'

SET @sSql = 'SELECT ' + CAST(@num1 AS nvarchar(255)) + @op + CAST(@num2 AS nvarchar(255))
EXEC sp_executesql @sSql
```

Depending on what you set your operator (@op) to will be what the operation is.
The above gives 0.0162735 as the result.